# I am not getting angular2-datepicker style location

Tags: angular

I am using angular-datepicker for selecting a date, I want to change the UI of the calendar (ex: color and text of the calendar)

please find the link , 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iflq2p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
presently the calender color is blue,
i want to change the color of the calender

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz with the expected output?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iflq2p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: As per my observation you can't! But I think there can be workaround for this:) Try to ask on GitHub: https://github.com/CuppaLabs/angular2-datetimepicker